# Find coordinates for points at the boundary

Tags: r, coordinates

I have a dataset with some X and Y coordinates. I want to find the coordinates of the points at the boundary in R. How do I go about doing this?
[image]

In this image, I have plotted the X and Y coordinates. If I want to identify the coordinates of the points surrounding the orange region, how may I do so? I have also attached a sample dataset to this post (with 19 rows).

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ypYai.png)

Comment: Hi, I have edited my post with more details and a supporting image. I apologise for the lack of details!

Comment: thanks for doing that! it's okay. I think the most obvious approach is to take some small number n, and check if within that point, if there are both orange and blue points. Then if yes, then it's a neighbouring point

Comment: It would be great though if you could include some code and/or data. Photos are bad for many reasons (which you can read about here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

Comment: Hi Mark, unfortunately since I'm using confidential data it is hard for me to include it in this post. Basically the dataset has 3 columns: X coordinates in one column, Y coordinates in another column, and 'Group' in a last column. The 'Group' column is either A or B leading to the orange/ green regions in the image. I want to identify the coordinates of the points that form the boundary between the two groups if that is possible!

Comment: in that case, write some code which can create similar data programatically, or anonymise the data. Either you do it, or the people who answer will be forced to do it (and in the second case, they will do a bad job, and people will be put off from answering because they know they will have to do it)

Answer (score 3):

One approach is to use an SVM to classify your points according to their X and Y values. Use, e.g. `svm` from {e1071} and grab the *decision value* for each point. For two classes (red and blue points) that's the reliability between -1 and 1 a point belongs to one or the other cluster. Values around zero ("unsure") occur along the boundaries, so you can filter for these. Some playing with the settings will be required for satisfactory results.

Example:

1. generate example data `d`:

```
structure(list(Xmean = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), Ymean = c(1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 9L), Class = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("a", 
"b"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, -36L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

```
d |> ggplot(aes(Xmean, Ymean)) +
        geom_label(aes(label = Class, col = Class))
```

[image: points of class a or b in a plane]

2. train a very basic SVM model `m`:

```
library(e1071)
m <- svm(Class ~ Ymean + Xmean, data = d,
         probability = TRUE
         )
```

3. add decision values from model to dataframe as a criterion for boundary points, plot for iterative optimisation:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

d |>
  mutate(decision_value = m$decision.values[,1], ## between -1 and 1
         is_border_point = abs(decision_value) < .5 ## optimize
         ) |>
  ggplot(aes(Xmean, Ymean)) +
  geom_label(aes(label = Class, col = Class, size = is_border_point))
```

[image: boundary points have centered decision values]